# Converting UITextField to String in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert a UITextField object to a String so that I can pass it to a function in my model file.  But it is printing a blank even after I type in some characters in the name input text field and then click outside of it.  Why is nothing stored there?

In view controller file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameInputText: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameInputText.delegate = self
    let text: String = nameInputText.text!
    print(text) //this prints a blank
    model.validateName(nametext: text)

}
```

Comment: You have this code inside of your `viewDidLoad` so are you sure that you have any text in your `nameInputText`?

Comment: This code happens when the controller loads. Did you put text in the text field first?

Comment: where should I put this so that the text gets loaded into variable?  Yes I typed in some characters in the text field.

Comment: @jean you should do it in `textFieldDidEndEditing`, see my answer.

Comment: I'm making an array of UITextFields to create.  Would I do that in the view did load function or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

It should be like below

```
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameInputText : UITextField!

      override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        usernameInputText.delegate = self
    }

    func ClickOnButton()
    {
      let text: String = usernameInputText.text!
        print(text) //this prints My text
        model.validateName(nametext: text)
    }

func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String)
        -> Bool
    {
       let text: String = usernameInputText.text!
        print(text) //this prints My text
        model.validateName(nametext: text)
    }
```

Comment: How does that make any sense to set the text of a `UITextField` programatically and then without changing its text from the UI send that text to a different function instead of sending the string itself?

Comment: Trying to get the the text that user enters though.

Comment: I have edited answer... Either you can call method on each text input or you can show button and on click on that button call method

Comment: @VibhaSingh You shouldn't read the value of a textfield in `textField(_ textField:UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)`, you should do it in `textFieldDidEndEditing` if you want to get the final value of the text field. Moreover, your function is incorrect, it doesn't return any value, while it needs to return a `Bool`.

Comment: this doesn't store the last letter user entered

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` gets called **before** your `ViewController` would be visible to the user, so any text field can only contain text if you have set that text before (in InterfaceBuilder or code). If you want to access user input from that text field, you should either do that in `textFieldDidEndEditing` or in any other function which you know can only be called after the user interaction happened.

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameInputText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameInputText.delegate = self
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        model.validateName(nametext: textField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I add let text: String = usernameInputText.text! to function textFieldDidEndEditing function?

Comment: I tried this extension function at it doesn't compile.  Out of scope.

Comment: The compiler probably has a problem with your `model.validateName` function, where did you define it? Don't use force unwrapping on the textField's text, but if you need to store the text for later use and not just for calling the validate function, then yes, store it in a variable.